# How to access a Javascript file from multiple html files

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have 2 html files, index.html, and example.html and they both use script.js.  If I were to use a statement like `document.createElement("p");` in the script, how would I specify which html file I want to make the paragraph in?

Comment: You wouldn't have two .html files linking to a single .js file that does that in the first place. If your .js file does things that pertain to only one file, then only have the one .html file link to it. Place code that is common to many .html files in a separate .js file.

Comment: @JohnSkilesSkinner That's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: First, document.createElement does not place an element. After you create it you'll need to place it on the page. That is where you would reference a specific element in the HTML file, to tell JS where the place the new element you've created. Your JS code does not care which HTML document called it (unless you tell it to). Every time your page is opened your JS code will execute, so if you link it in both pages it will execute the same code. JS does not edit the HTML directly, it just changes what the user views. With that in mind I'm not sure how to answer you question.

Comment: @Skeik This OP is not asking how to add the element to the page. The OP is asking how to limit the code to work only on one of two pages that reference the script.

Comment: @scott-marcus I'm not sure what OP is asking yet which is why I gave some info looking for clarification. If he doesn't care about editing the DOM then why specifically mention a method that concerns it? If this is not what OP is asking he should clarify himself, because more people than not are confused.

Comment: @Skeik *because more people than not are confused* <-- That's why I commented. To help clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to play with classes/IDs. The JavaScript file will work on whichever DOM is loaded, whether it's a DOM based on your first HTML or the second.

If you were to do this, you could--in theory--have a specific ID on one HTML file and another ID on the other. Your JS file can append the paragraph to the node with that ID, but only if the ID is actually on the DOM.

This is far from ideal though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the element to be created in every HTML file in which the JS file is included, the code should be invoked from the HTML file as appropriate. For example, you would add a `<script>` block in the HTML file that calls `createMyElement`, and `createMyElement` would be a function in the shared JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you intend on injecting the paragraph element? You could give each section a different id and do something along the lines of :

```js
function InjectHtmlElement(bodyId, element, modifyBodyCallBack)
{
  let body = ducement.getElementById(bodyId);
  
  if(body == null)
  {
    return
  }
  modifyBodyCallBack(body, element);
}
```

```html
<body id="first"></body>




<body id="second"></body>
```

This isn't ideal but it'll work.

Answer (score -1):

by appending the node element to an element in the desired file.

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

to learn more about [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking.